# Google Forms Regular Expressions (REGEX) comma delaminated (CSV)

Tags: regex, google-forms

I have a Google form field, that contains 1 or more Id's

**Patterns:**

- The IDs are always 6 numbers.
- If only one ID is entered, a comma and a space is NOT required.
- If more than one ID is entered, a comma and a space is required.
- If more than one ID is entered, the last ID, should not have a comma or a space at the end.

**Allowed Examples:**

- a single ID: 123456
- multiple ID: 123456, 456789, 987654

**Here is my current REGEX (does not work correctly)**

`[0-9]{6}[,\s]?([0-9]{6}[,\s])*[0-9]?`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d{6}(?:,\s\d{6})*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{6}` Match 6 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `,\s\d{6}` Match a `,` a whitespace char and 6 digits
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6kE9AM/1)

Comment: This worked perfectly, and was far easier to understand as a beginner. Thank you!.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^((?:\d{6})(?:(?:,\s+\d{6}){1,})?)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/HYYxlS/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation of above regex.

```
^(                     ##Checking from starting of value, creating single capturing group.
   (?:\d{6})           ##Checking if there are 6 digits in a non-capturing group here.
   (?:                 ##Creating 1st non-capturing group here
      (?:,\s+\d{6})    ##In a non-capturing group checking it has comma space(1 or more occurrences) followed by 6 digits here.
   ){1,})?             ##Closing 1st non-capturing group here, it could have 1 or more occurrences of it.
)$                     ##Closing 1st capturing group here with $ to make sure its end of value.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and very detailed explanation which helped me learn more. The code you provided works perfectly, except that it allows "1" as a valid ID. In my case, all ID's must be 6 characters long.

Comment: @JamesReed68, oh sorry, I thought 1 is valid here :( let me edit it.

Comment: Ah! I see where the confusion was. That was my fault. I have updated my question from "If only 1 ID is entered, a comma and a space is NOT required." to "If only one ID is entered, a comma and a space is NOT required."

Comment: @JamesReed68, not an issue, its been fixed it now, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Working perfectly now. To get a bit of a better understanding on regex, is there any benefit to using your code `^((?:\d{6})(?:(?:(?:,\s+\d{6})){1,})?)$` over the other code `^\d{6}(?:,\s\d{6})*$` posted by @The fourth bird? They appear different, yet have the same results (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @JamesReed68, I have just additionally added few non-capturing groups, working wise they will be same(and logic wise they are same only). Well actually speaking that 1 digit confused me, else most probably I would have written closed to same what @ The fourth bird has written, to be honest(his is better than mine in terms of short and crisp:)), cheers.

Comment: I truly appreciate your honesty and expiation! Thanks! Cheers! :)